# Identify if a value in one DataFrame exists in another for each record

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to identify if a value from one DataFrame for each record exists in another DataFrame.

For example, in DF1 below there are two values against "Mike" - "A" and "B". In DF2, we can see "A" exists, but "G" doesn't against Mike. For Karen, we can see that "JK" is there, but not "B". And so on.

Note that the actual columns names here don't matter.

The final output would therefore tell me whether a value has been found for each record, or not found. Struggling to get started with this though.

**DF1**

| TITLE | ATT1 | ATT2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | A | G |
| Karen | B | JK |
| John | D | H |

**DF2**

| NAME | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | A | H | W |
| John | D | H | E |
| Karen | F | JK | EE |
| Aaron | F | BB | E |

**Output**

| TITLE | ATT1 | ATT2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | FOUND | NOT FOUND |
| Karen | NOT FOUND | FOUND |
| John | FOUND | FOUND |

Answer (score 1):

You could first create a new column in df1 with all the column values in df2 in a list using [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and [`map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
df1['df2_col_values'] = df1['title'].map(df2.set_index('name').T.to_dict(orient='list'))
```

Then create your output dataframe by checking whether for att1 and att2 there is a match in df2_col_values, assuming there are only att1 and att2 for which you want to check if there is a match

```
output = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index)
output.insert(0, 'title', df1['title'])

for col in ('att1', 'att2'):
    output[col] = df1.apply(lambda x: x[col] in x['df2_col_values'], axis=1).map({True: 'Found', False: 'Not Found'})
```

Output:

|  | title | att1 | att2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Mike | Found | Not Found |
| 1 | Karen | Not Found | Found |
| 2 | John | Found | Found |

Answer (score 1):

With combination of [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (to perform left inner merge) + [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) (for broadcastable element containment check):

```
df_ = df1.merge(df2, left_on='TITLE', right_on='NAME', how='left')
res = (pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([df1['TITLE'], 
                    np.where(np.isin(df_[df1.columns[1:]], df_[df2.columns[1:]]), 
                                     'FOUND', 'NOT FOUND')]), 
       columns=df1.columns))
```

---

```
   TITLE       ATT1       ATT2
0   Mike      FOUND  NOT FOUND
1  Karen  NOT FOUND      FOUND
2   John      FOUND      FOUND
```

Comment: Thanks. Think this might work. Should have mentioned that some of the columns between df1 and df2 and the same name, which can cause issues with your solution. But I may just add a random suffix to the end of the all df2 columns to fix that

Comment: @TheDataPanda, if so, post the dataframes with relevant, actual column names to get a more precise view-picture

Answer (score 0):

You can try the new [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html) :

```
d = (df2.melt("NAME", ignore_index=False)
     .set_index("value")["NAME"].to_dict())

out = (
    df1.set_index("TITLE").map(
        lambda v: "FOUND" if d.get(v) else "NOT FOUND")
        .reset_index()
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   TITLE       ATT1       ATT2
0   Mike      FOUND  NOT FOUND
1  Karen  NOT FOUND      FOUND
2   John      FOUND      FOUND
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `set`s for each row and mapping to `TITLE` column with testing by [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint):

```
d = {k: set(v) for k, v in  df2.set_index('NAME').T.items()}

f = lambda x: ['NOT FOUND' if set(k).isdisjoint([v]) else 'FOUND' for k, v in x.items()]
out = df1.set_index('TITLE').rename(d).apply(f).set_index(df1['TITLE']).reset_index()
print (out)
   TITLE       ATT1       ATT2
0   Mike      FOUND  NOT FOUND
1  Karen  NOT FOUND      FOUND
2   John      FOUND      FOUND
```

You can use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
out = (df1.melt('TITLE')
         .merge(df2.melt('NAME'), left_on='TITLE', right_on='NAME', how='left')
         .assign(new=lambda x: x.value_x.eq(x.value_y),
                 TITLE=lambda x: pd.Categorical(x['TITLE'],
                                                ordered=True, 
                                                categories=df1['TITLE'].unique()))
         .pivot_table(index='TITLE', columns='variable_x', values='new', aggfunc='any')
         .replace({True:'FOUND', False:'NOT FOUND'})
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
         .reset_index())
print (out)
   TITLE       ATT1       ATT2
0   Mike      FOUND  NOT FOUND
1  Karen  NOT FOUND      FOUND
2   John      FOUND      FOUND
```